# 'self' is not defined when calling eval list comprehension with if statement in Python 3.7.5

Tags: python, list-comprehension, eval, nameerror

I encountered a problem while using `eval()`  to evaluate a list comprehension with an if statement in Python 3.7.5.
The issue occurred within the following class `foo`, which contains two methods: `exe` and `listcomp`.

When calling `foo.listcomp()`, both list comprehensions work correctly.
However, when using the `exe()`  method with each list comprehensions inside `foo.listcomp()`, only the first list comprehension works, and the second list comprehension raises a `NameError`.

The code structure is as follows:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = [1,2,3]
        self.num = 'q'
    def exe(self, v):
        res = eval(v, globals(), locals())
        print(res)
    def listcomp(self):
        print([a for a in self.list])
        print([a for a in self.list if a == self.num])
```

So, `foo.exe('[a for a in self.list]')` worked, but `foo.exe('[a for a in self.list if a == self.num]')` raised the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in exe
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <listcomp>
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I don't know what's the difference between them and why the error happens.

I have tried to make the `self`  variable accessible within the evaluated expression by passing `globals()`  and `locals()`  to `eval()`, but I have not been successful.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to overcome this issue and make the second list comprehension work within the `exe()` method.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) inquiry: what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Presumably you actually called `foo().exe` since your code won't run as written.  And I agree with `Chris`.  Why are you using `eval`? This is almost always a mistake.

Comment: But despite my previous comment, this seems really strange.

Comment: @Chris
I'm creating a simple web crawler that allows users to control its actions.
The main objective is to have a crawler instance read a text file containing the URL of the target page and the commands to execute, and then eval() them line-by-line. It is kind of REPL (read-eval-print-loop) style.
The class mentioned in the question is a simplified version of the crawler class to show my problem --unable to inject list comprehension (especially with an if statement) for execution inside an instance--.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Keep in mind that evaling that means _whatever is in the string `v`_ will be evaled.